# Is this hadith authentic? and if so please provide the reference

Tags: authenticity

Muawiyah Ibn Sufyan (Ra) relates that the Prophet (saw) said, “There is a group among my followers who will continue to be openly on the truth. No one who opposes them can harm them until the coming of the Hour”. The Companions (RA) asked, “Where will they be”? The Messenger of Allah said, “They will be in and around Bayt Al-Maqdis (i.e. Jerusalem)”.
[Ahmad]

Comment: As you may read in your post the reference is already quoted (Ahmad) = Musnad imam Ahmad. If you check the site a suppose that this hadith was already mentioned in a question or answer.

Comment: https://al-maktaba.org/book/25794/18516